# About MIB handling of agent in SNMP

Tags: c, object, snmp, agent, mib

I'm developing the agent in SNMP and I have a question related to MIB file:
How does the agent get/set the values of object from MIB (I think "MIB" only refers to the definition of objects without values)?  How do I manage device handle value of an object from a MIB file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write a SNMP agent, you have to follow some steps.

> 1. List item
>    First define your MIB . In the MIB expose create/set/get operations
>    for different objects. These objects are grouped in a tree.
> 2. Write the Parser module that would parse the MIBs and get the data
>    models from them.
> 3. Write transport modules, message processor modules and message
>    dispatcher modules.
> 4. Adhere to the standard SNMP PDU format when defining the data over
>    the transport (over the Network).
> 5. After the message is received from the transport, your Message
>    processing module at the agent side has got to check few things like
>    authentication and authorization (in case of SNMP v3), check for the
>    availability of the OID (check if it is defined in the MIB or not) and
>    other checks if there are any.
>
> If everything is successful then create response PDU and send back with same request Id to the manager which initiated the request.

Check out [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/) and [snmp4j](http://www.snmp4j.org/) for further ideas on development as you don't have to write everything from the scratch and make use of those freely available libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your teaching. I would like to ask you some question, please help me to improve my knowledge.
 In step 1: I have defined MIB in a file (i wrote by ANS.1). In the my code, should i make  the Tree that have nodes (that is objects) appropriate to modules in MIB file ? is create/set/get operation a method in each object?  
In step 2: Does Parser Module parser MIB file to get data model for each object in above Tree?